# Saving variable get_pdf() into fields.binary

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I want to save a variable automatically into a fields.binary (email_attachment_file) from get_pdf function.

My codes below here:

```py
 class example_example(models.Model):
    email_attachment_file   =   fields.Binary('Data (.txt,.pdf)')
    email_filename          =   fields.Char('Filename')

    def generate(self,etc..):
      report_name = "report_name_template"

      datas = {
            'ids':[],
            'model' : etc,
            'form'  : etc
            'context': context
            }

      moddelReport = self.pool.get('report')
      alpha =  modelReport.get_pdf(cr, uid,[],report_name,None,datas,context=context)  

      #alpha = base64.decodestring(alpha)
      #alpha = alpha.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8')

      # --------- how to save alpha variable into fields.binary
```

And, is there something wrong modelReport.get_pdf function ?

Answer (score 2):

Use **encodestring()** instead of **decodestring()**.

```
report_obj = self.pool.get('report')
data =  modelReport.get_pdf(cr, uid,[],report_name,None,datas,context=context)
self.email_attachment_file  = base64.encodestring(data)
```

Comment: the return from data is %PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<<
/Kids [ ]
/Type /Pages
/Count 0
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Producer (Python PDF Library \055 http\072\057\057pybrary\056net\057pyPdf\057).. etc..., i can't figure it out to find the solution

Comment: get_pdf return the report as a string format so, you need to convert it in the binary by using base64.encodestring(data).